# django - ModelAdmin prepopulated foreignkey

Tags: django, django-forms, django-admin

I have three models: Customer, Contract, Report

```
class Customer
    pass

class Contract
    customer = models.ForeignKey(Customer)

class Report
    customer = models.ForeignKey(Customer)
    contract = models.ForeignKey(Contract, null=True, blank=True, default=None)
```

In admin when edit Report I want to select Customer OR Contract, and if I select contract customer must be set to Contract's customer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your **admin.py** override save method:

```
def save_model(self, request, obj, form, change):
    if obj.contract:
        obj.customer = obj.contract.customer # set customer to related contract customer
    else:
        #probably you do not do anything in here
    obj.save()
```